# permutation -number of numbers of four different digits formed from the digits of the number 12356 such that it is divisible by 4

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The number of numbers of four different digits that can be formed from the digits of the number 12356 such that it is divisible by 4??

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If a number ends in $12$, $32$, $52$, $16$, $36$, $56$, it is multiple of $4$. How many ways can you fill the other two digits?

Comment: total ways will be 36-thankyou..got the answer

Answer (score -2):

The answer to this is quite simple. Adding to what [@ajotatxe](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/132456/ajotatxe) has written, any number is divisible by $4$, if the last $2$ digits are multiples of $4$. From the given list the following are possible in the last $2$ places: **$12, 16,32, 36,52, 56$**. 
Hence **$6$** ways.

Now, the remaining $2$ digits can be any of the $3$ digits from the list, as $2$ have been used up in the last $2$ places.

Therefore, the total number of ways is: **$3 \times 2 \times 6 = 36$** **total ways**

**Note:** I have made the necessary edits to my answer. Apologies as I had mistaken the question... And a bunch of thanks to [@Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer)

Comment: Only the digits $1,2,3,5,6$ are available, not $4$. You seem to have "auto-corrected" that to "the digits from $1$ to $6$". If $4$ were also available, there would indeed be 108 such numbers. But since only five digits can be used, the number is 36.

Comment: Even if $4$ were in the list, $44$ uses it twice, which is disallowed.